# How to use self-compiled Python from an Upstart script on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bash, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, upstart

I'm trying to use a custom self-compiled Python version installed under "/opt" from an Upstart script on Ubuntu 14.04. General setup looks like following:

- The service configuration file defines a pre-start script which calls some bash script from a user (non-root) directory
- This bash script defines a trap error function calling some Python code
- The trap error function is defined as

  ```
  function error_handler()
  {
      python << END
      # python code...
      END
  }
  trap 'error_handler ${LINENO} $?' ERR
  ```
- Any 3rd party side-packages are installed under "/opt" as well using pip from custom Python installation
- PATH env variable for this non-root user includes a binary folder under /opt where custom Python could be found
- the ".bashrc" file was modified to be executed for non-interactice log-ins
- I have also tried to use a ".bash_profile" file and just called ".bashrc" from it

  > In the log files under "/var/log/upstart/service.log", I see errors messages saying that any installed 3rd party Python side-package couldn't be found. These packages are installed under "/opt"

The custom Python installation itself works as expected. I can run any Python code and import any of the installed side-packages.

What I have tried so far to get it working as a service:

- Update the PATH env varibale for a given user
- Call the bash script from the "pre-start" section using the `sudo -u user_name` command
- Modify the PATH env variable inside of the bash script:

  ```
  PATH=/opt/bin:$PATH
  export PATH
  function error_handler()
  {
      PATH="$PATH" python << END
      # python code...
      END
  }
  trap 'error_handler ${LINENO} $?' ERR
  ```
- Set `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH env` variables
- Update the library search path from the Python code using `sys.path.append` before importing any of the 3rd party side-packages

Here is my question: How can I convince the Startup service to pick up the Python version I want to run and to use packages installed under "/opt"?

Basically, I want to use Python 2.7.9 on Ubuntu 14.04. I couldn't find any pre-compiled Ubuntu 14.04 package so far.

Comment: As an addition: Python 2.7.9 on Ubuntu 14.04 would be one solution to solve our problem. What we exactly need is Python 2.7 with TLS1_2 support.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to use our self-compiled Python by adding the `setuid` call to the service configuration and by a proper usage of the Python virtual environments.

Oleg